# How to reference static resources in <style> tag

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a `<div>` with a conditional class that provides a border around some content. The border image is in the `<project>/static/borders` folder.

```html
<script>
import config from '$lib/data/config'
</script>

<div class:borderimg={config.traits['has-borders']} >
    <SomeContentHere/>
</div>

<style>
    .borderimg {
        border: 30px solid transparent;
        border-image-source: url(/border/border.png);
        border-image-slice: 100;
    }
</style>
```

When I `npm run build`, the image is not found.  I have had to work-around this by specifying the border image in a conditional style.

```html
<script>
import config from '$lib/data/config';
import { base } from '$app/paths';
</script>

<div class:borderimg={config.traits['has-borders']} 
     style:border-image-source={config.traits['has-borders']
        ? 'url(' + base + '/borders/border.png)'
        : ''} 
>
    <SomeContentHere/>
</div>

<style>
    .borderimg {
        border: 30px solid transparent;
        border-image-slice: 100;
    }
</style>
```

In static CSS files, I can use `$lib/assets/` to reference static resources (e.g. `$lib/assets/fonts/fontname.ttf`). I tried using `$lib/assets/borders/border.png` in the `<style>` element, but that didn't work. It complains during the build:

> [vite:css] [postcss] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[redacted]/src/lib/assets/borders/border.png'

Q: So it is trying to do some checking if $lib is used.  Is there another variable I should use?

Q: Should I put the resource in lib folder instead of the static folder?

I had been using just `/borders/border.png` which works during development time, but doesn't work at build time.

> /borders/border.png referenced in [redacted]/src/routes/+page.svelte?svelte&type=style&lang.css didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime

The generated css for the component is stored in `_app/immutable/assets` so I can use `../../../borders/border.png`, but that doesn't seem the best.

Answer (score 0):

`$lib` is simply an alias for a directory, if you want to use it, which I would recommend since the assets get hashed, you have to move your files into the corresponding location.

There is nothing really special about this, it just gets substituted and the build system tries to process referenced assets. The files also do not have to be in any subfolder, it can just be directly in `src/lib`, or *anywhere else* for that matter, like right next to the `+page` file. As long as the URL can be resolved it will either be extracted as an asset or inlined into the CSS (if it is very small).